# Origin of the slang "機車"

Tags: translation, etymology, meaning-in-context, slang

I know that "機車" is motorcycle and it is also used as a slang word, but I was unsure of its meaning. Thus, i checked [this page](http://www.chtoen.com/%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD%E6%A9%9F%E8%BB%8A%E7%9A%84%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87%E6%80%8E%E9%BA%BC%E8%AA%AA), and I was confused by its ambiguity when translated to English, as listed below:

> - indecisive
> - temperamental
> - fickle/flaky/capricious
> - stubborn
> - demanding
> - jerk

Is jerk the English equivalent of "機車"? If not, is there an English equivalent? What was the origin of this slang meaning? I cannot find any correlation between "motorcycle" and any of the meanings listed...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 机车  iciba [铁道] locomotive； engine ； haulage motor ； loco
 小马词典：locomotive; train engine car; scooter (Taiwan); hard to get along with (Taiwan slang)
iciba：摩托车，motorcycle

Comment: Yeah that doesn't even begin to answer the question.....

Comment: 该评论的目的为提醒大家普通话里＂机车＂是什么意思以及motorcycle在普通话里叫做什么。另外好象值得注意的是问题所提出＂机车＂的特殊意义似乎仅限于台湾。根据小马词典甚至在台湾俚语里＂机车＂是表示＂小型摩托车＂的意思而不是 ＂摩托车＂。users are supposed to avoid answering questions in comments 用户应该避免用评论回答问题

Comment: @S.Rhee I guess user3306356 meant that your comment is not helpful at all to my question, but I do find the meaning "hard to get along with" helpful. Perhaps the format is confusing and lowers the readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Taiwanese slang.

> 機車：在台灣有時會用來形容人難以相處，作為一種罵人用語。由來為台灣閩南人中，部分人士對於令人不滿
>       的人會以粗俗詞語「欠姦」（閩南話）來形容，甚至以「膣屄」（閩南話，發音類似「機掰」）取代「欠姦」，
>       但由於感到不雅或故意作為玩笑，起於民國80年代的學生族群，有一些人「機……」第一個音發出後，第二個
>       音改接「車」而成為「機車」。

ref : [wikipedia of 機車](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A9%9F%E8%BB%8A)

Comment: Didn't expect this to be on wikipedia...Thank you!